# Xcode Sqlite Encoding Turkish characters

Tags: objective-c, database, xcode, sqlite

We have records like 'GÜLHAN', 'Yılan', 'çekiç' in our Sqlite database.
These words include Turkish characters and the problem is that we can not read these words correctly, for example; we read 'GEDf∞k' instead of 'GEDİK'.

How can we solve this sqlite reading problem in xcode?

Answer (score 2):

What encoding did you use to store data in DB? Should not be any problems if it's UTF8.

```
char *data = (char *) sqlite3_column_text (stmt, 1);
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:data];
```

If this gives you unexpected results, then it's not UTF8 and it's probably a good idea to re-encode everything in DB to UTF8 first.

Comment: +1: SQLite wants the strings to be UTF-8. I'd expect `GEDİK` to be stored as `GEDÄ°K` (byte-wise interpretation).